# smartparensとweb-modeを同時に使うと > が1つ余計に補完されてしまう

Tags: emacs, elisp, erb

Emacs 24.4を使用しています。

smartparensとweb-modeを同時に使用していると、erbファイルを扱っている時に`>`がひとつ多く補完されてしまうことがあります。

具体的には`<%=`と入力すると、 `%>>`のように、`>`がひとつ多く補完されます。
どうもsmartparensが `<`が入力された時点で `>` を補完し、その後 `%=` が入力された時点でweb-modeが `%>` を補完しているようです。`<%` と入力してスペースを入力した場合も同じです。

これを解消するにはどのように設定すればよいでしょうか。

回避策として、web-mode.elの８４４行目から８４７行目を

```
("erb"         . (("<% " . " %")
                  ("<%=" . "%")
                  ("<%#" . "%")
                  ("<%-" . "%")))
```

と書き換えることでも解決出来るのですが、これ以外にスマートな解決方法が知りたいです。

Comment: ただ単に両モードを有効にしても再現しないのですが, 何か特別な設定はされているのでしょうか ? 設定があるなら, そちらも示せていただければと思います. それとも特別な状況下で起こる問題ということでしょうか ?

Comment: smartparensについては有効にしているだけです。
web-modeについても関係しそうな設定はしていないと思うのですが。
ＵＲＬの５７５行目からがweb-modeの設定です。
https://github.com/wat-aro/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el

Comment: 両方とも最新版を使われているでしょうか ? https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/164 を見ると修正されているように思えます.

Comment: @syohex 両方一ヶ月前のものでしたので最新版を入れてみましたが、同じ症状が出ました.

Answer (score 1):

[web-mode.el - html template editing for emacs](http://web-mode.org/)の “I want to use smartparens” を読んでください。

この回答を書いてる時点では`sp-web-mode-is-code-context`を定義して`sp-local-pair`を設定する方法が紹介されてゐます。